# Remove SubString from String base on two strings or parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Say I have the following string:

`<p>Apple.</p><remove>Lettuce.</remove><span>Orange.</span>`

I would like the output to be:

`<p>Apple.</p><span>Orange.</span>`

So I am trying to build a method like this:

```
def remove_this_block('<remove','/remove>')
  # some code here
end
```

I've tried `gsub`, `strip_tags`, etc... Nothing seems to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) would do:

```
"<p>Apple.</p><remove>Lettuce.</remove><span>Orange.</span>".
  gsub /<remove.*?\/remove>/, ''
#⇒ "<p>Apple.</p><span>Orange.</span>"
```

Comment: Negated character set is generally faster than lazy quantifier, I wrote about it: https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698

Comment: @mrzasa Yes, but you can use negated character set only when the pattern you are avoiding is single-character long.

Comment: Yup, that's why I match whole tags in my answer.

Comment: @mrzasa Nope, please see my comment to your answer.